# SQL SELECT last canceled service for group of related user records

Tags: sql, select, distinct, row-number

A user can have at most one active service record (or none), but many previous canceled service records.  I'm trying to SELECT the most recent canceled service record for each user, or nothing if the last service record is NOT canceled.  I think ROW_NUMBER is required, but I'm unable to figure out the proper SELECT statement. Here are the details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a [great article](https://learnsql.com/blog/first-row-of-each-group-sql/) that allowed me to craft a suitable SQL query using *Window Functions and Common Table Expressions*.  I used the term "service" in my original post, but you can substitute that with "subscription" and tweak the columns a bit, and come up with a brief query such as:

```
WITH partionedRows AS (
SELECT
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sub.UserId ORDER BY sub.CreateDate DESC) AS userSubscriptionCancelRank
    , sub.Id AS SubscriptionId
FROM
    Subscription sub
    JOIN AspNetUsers u on u.Id = sub.UserId
)
SELECT
    userSubscriptionCancelRank
    , sub. UserId
    , u.Email
    , sub.Id
    , sub.CreateDate
    , sub.CancelDate
FROM
    partionedRows pr
    JOIN Subscription sub on sub.Id = pr.SubscriptionId
    JOIN AspNetUsers u on u.Id = sub.UserId
WHERE
    userSubscriptionCancelRank = 1
    AND sub.CancelDate IS NOT NULL
```

Beautimous, maximous.